# what is the limitations of the html's mailto url

Tags: html, mailto

In my portfolio projects, i append a `'mailto:email@provider.com'` in some a tag as a way of contacting me. But, what is the situations that this works? In my computer, it opens the windows 10 email app, but what happens in other situations, like someone that doesn't have an email app(windows 7 users maybe) or someone using mac?

Comment: Revisiting some of my old answers. @micow27404 - if this helped solve your problem, can you kindly mark this answer correct by clicking the checkmark? It will help others who have similar issues in the future. - Happy coding!

Answer (score 1):

If you use mailto and the user does not have email software installed and does not have a pre-existing operation that should happen in correlation with a mailto link, nothing would happen.

When using the mailto link, you are making the assumption that the recipient(s) have email software installed on their machine, or that their browser will know what to do when the mailto URL is clicked.